# Converted images to pdf are too vibrant

Tags: macos, shell, imagemagick, img2pdf

When I do

`img2pdf input.jpg -o output.pdf`

, the output pdf is too vibrant, and not a one-to-one with the image. I also tried it with ImageMagick and

`convert input.jpg output.pdf`

is also too vibrant.

I was expecting a one-to-one like how MacOS' `Create PDF` does it, but I can't use it because I don't think it has a CLI equivalent, and I would rather not lock myself in with MacOS only tools. I need it to be usable on the CLI to automate several tasks with scripting. I just noticed the difference, and I've been searching for a couple of hours, but couldn't find an answer to my problem. Is this intentional? Or a bug? It's driving me mad!

Comment: Post your input jpg

Comment: I can't really since it's kind of private. But you can use this [random image](https://www.travelandleisure.com/thmb/KTIha5CLifSoUD3gx0YP51xc3rY=/1500x0/filters:no_upscale():max_bytes(150000):strip_icc()/blue0517-4dfc85cb0200460ab717b101ac07888f.jpg) I found on the internet. It's just a shade of blue, but when you convert it, it becomes more saturated or something. I'd also like to mention I've tried this with .png and .webp, so I don't think it's a .jpg problem. The effect is also consistent from image to image.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me to convert from jpg to png in Imagemagick 6.9.12.93 on my Mac OSX Ventura

```
convert blue.jpg x.png
compare -metric rmse blue.jpg x.png null:
0 (0)
```

Same result converting to PDF

```
convert blue.jpg x.pdf
bash-3.2$ compare -metric rmse blue.jpg x.pdf null:
0 (0)
```

What is your IM version?

Your jpg has no profile. You might want to add an sRGB.icc color profile before converting. That often helps as some viewers and systems handle that differently (add or don't add the profile automatically).

Comment: `convert --version

Version: ImageMagick 7.1.1-13 Q16-HDRI aarch64 21276 https://imagemagick.org
Copyright: (C) 1999 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: https://imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC HDRI Modules OpenMP(5.0) 
Delegates (built-in): bzlib fontconfig freetype gslib heic jng jp2 jpeg jxl lcms lqr ltdl lzma openexr png ps raw tiff webp xml zlib
Compiler: gcc (4.2)
`

Comment: Also, I tried compare on the jpg and a PDF created using ImageMagick and a PDF created using the MacOS `CreatePDF`utility, but I didn't get a difference. Yet I clearly see it. And I'm using Preview for images and PDFs.

Comment: Okay, this is very weird: when I open the PDFs in Safari or Chrome, I no longer see the difference. It seems to be a preview specific problem. But I'd still like to know why it happens in preview and quick look. Should I report this as a bug to Apple?

Comment: I played around further, and when I changed the display preset to `Internet & Web (sRGB)` from the default `Apple XDR Display (P3-1600 nits)`, the difference disappeared, but the display is now difficult to look at. And I still don't understand why `CreatePDF` and `ImageMagick` do things differently...

Answer (score 0):

Also works fine for me. If I

- convert the JPG to PDF with IM,
- display both **using the same file viewer** (`Okular`)
- Take a screenshot that includes these two image viewer windows
- Measure the blue in each window in the screen shot

I get the very same color on both sides.

If you use different apps to check the JPG and the PDF, the PDF viewer could be adding "pop" to the image.